# Node.js error callback

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I have a codebase which contains code similar to the code below many times:

```
function(doc, callback) {
  doSomething(function(err) {
    if(err) return callback(err);

    callback(null, doc);
  });
}
```

I'm wondering if there are any downsides to just combining the explicit error check into:

```
function(doc, callback) {
  doSomething(function(err) {        
    callback(err, doc);
  });
}
```

I understand that callback handlers are expected to check the err on callback, but in this case it's just bubbling up.

I suppose I'm wondering if based on the way callbacks are generally used, if this is an issue?

Comment: your approach is fine if you don't need to handle `(err, doc)` before calling back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference, the code is doing the same thing. First one is just easier to edit later if you want to add some postprocessing.

Technically, second example provides a "doc" and first don't, but if somebody rely on that, they're doing it very wrong.